# How to access the Program counter registers for a multi core ARM CPU

Tags: arm, multicore

As per my understanding there are individual program counters for each ARM Core (if its quad core there will be 4 individual program counters which will point to 4 different locations of code for parallel execution).

Is my understanding correct? If yes, how can I access each of these program counters(for example in assembly language. Is it like this `PC[0], PC[1],PC[2], PC[3]`?

Comment: There are 4 _CPUs_. Each one individually behaves exactly like a single CPU, because that's what it is. One CPU cannot access another's registers directly, so the premise of the question makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly the same way you do on single-core ARM because each process on your system executes on its own core at any exact moment (can switch to another core but it depends) and sees its own single program counter.

Comment: Could you let me know how can I swith to a core - I mean is there a specific register where we can say which CPU registers are we manipulating now ?

Comment: @robomon You can't "switch to" a core as such at the code level - all CPUs will come up executing the same code at the reset address, so you would typically have some very early logic (possibly baked into the bootloader) to read the MPIDR and conditionally branch based on the value, in order to send different cores off in different directions. Alternatively, the primary CPU might do something to change the actual code that at the reset vector before bringing up the secondaries, for a similar effect.

Comment: As I understood, all the CPU's would start executing the same code. At some point they would check in which CPU they are executing in. Example - If you are CPU0 then branch to another code, if you are CPU1 then branch to another and it goes.

Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Yes, each cpu is separate but they either start the same place and then have to say if I am cpu0 then jump to cpu0 code, and so on or depending on the chip and/or software you might make it so they boot in different places. (change the reset vector, release one cpu, change the reset vector, release another, etc).

Comment: initially think of this as four completely separate computers that have the ability to communicate with each other (like the computers being used on so to read this, separate but communicate via ethernet/internet).  Then start to improve the communication to the point they share some resources.  They are four separate processors running independently, unless the chip (and core) have provided hooks, one cannot look into the other, and there is certainly no notion of who is running now as once started all four of them are running AT THE SAME TIME.

Comment: think of it as four separate computers that share a network hard drive (in addition to their own local hard drive and other resources).  instead the ram is shared as well as the other peripherals...so as LennyB has said treat each as single core arm from a program counter perspective, because they are.